# Do regex understand what adjectives and verbs are?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
sentence = 'horses are fast'
regex = re.compile('(?P<animal>\w+) (?P<verb>\w+) (?P<adjective>\w+)')
matched = re.search(regex, sentence)
print(matched.groupdict())
```

This code snippet produces the output

{'adjective': 'fast', 'verb': 'are', 'animal': 'horses'}

Two questions.

One how does the pattern match the sentence? Two does the matched object also contain the pattern used to create it?

Comment: Regex knows nothing of English grammar by itself.  Use your pattern on the following sentence and you will see what I mean: `Are horses fast?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, regular expressions simply define a search pattern. You need something more robust for part-of-speech tagging, i.e. the [NLTK library](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html).

```
regex = re.compile('(?P<animal>\w+) (?P<verb>\w+) (?P<adjective>\w+)')
```

All this line does is capture each group in sequence and then name it. [See here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) as well as the section below it titled "Non-capturing and Named Groups"